# CRUD OPERATION USING HTML and MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, parameters, undefined

Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index1.php on line 32

1. > Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
   >   in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index1.php on line 32
2. > Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
   >   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index1.php on line 43 Notice:
   >   Undefined variable: update in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index1.php on line
   >   69

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD: CReate, Update, Delete PHP MySQL</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>

    <div class="msg">
        <?php
            echo $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
            ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif?>
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                $id = $_GET['edit'];
                $update = true;
                $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id=$id");

                if (count($record) == 1) {
                    $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
                    $name = $n['name'];
                    $address = $n['address'];
                }
            }
        ?>

<?php

$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM info");?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="server.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>

<form>
    <form method="post" action="php_code.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <?php if ($update == true): ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >update</button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
<?php endif?>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
                      2ND FILE

<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud');

$name = "";
$address = "";
$id = 0;
$update = false;

if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO info (name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Address saved";
    header('location: index.php');
}
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE info SET name='$name', address='$address' WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Address updated!";
    header('location: index.php');
}
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $id = $_GET['del'];
    mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM info WHERE id=$id");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Address deleted!";
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index1.php on line 32 is telling you the problem,you try to use $db before it is assinged

Comment: tell me how to assign then ?

Comment: Take a good look at your 2ND FILE

Comment: AND don't use this code on a public server, your SQL query are not safe. sql injection is possible. learn prepared statements and/or how to sanitize your variables w3schools has some nice examples

Comment: in 2nd file scroll down

Comment: $db_host     = "localhost";
$db_name = " ";
$db_location = " ";
$db_name     = "crud";
$conn= mysqli_connect ($db_host,$db_name, $db_location,$db_name)or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysqli_select_db($conn,"crud") or die ("no database"); 

$results = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM info");  i make a connection but still give the same error

Comment: change $db to $conn, you assinged your connection to $conn but use $db in your query

Comment: yep the error is removed but still this error is coming   *Undefined variable: update*

Comment: yep it is removed thank you so much GOD bless you

Comment: one thing more my table and form collide each other do you have any idea how to split actually i want to say name and location at left and data enter will be on right side without using CSS and BOOTStrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And your code is fully prone to SQL injection

Read about the PHP Prepared statements. 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Suppose file 1 name is codefile.php and file 2 containing connection is connection.php So, write in codefile.php `include("connection.php")`
Change $db to $conn in codefile.php as in connection.php, you have created connection in $conn variable

**Check below link:**
w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

> codefile.php

```
 <?php
    include("connection.php");
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM info");
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CRUD: CReate, Update, Delete PHP MySQL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    ..................
    ..................
    ..................
```

> connection.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_location = " "; 
$db_name = "crud"; 
$conn= mysqli_connect ($db_host,$db_name, $db_location,$db_name)or die ("could not connect to mysql");
..................
..................
..................
```

Comment: yep i remove that error but i still got one error          *Undefined variable: update*

Comment: Have you added include line at top of file 1 @hafsahnajeeb Do one thing. Add your updated code in your question. So, we can check new errors.

Comment: yep the error is removed thanks for your support

Comment: one thing more my table and form collide each other do you have any idea how to split actually i want to say name and location at left and data enter will be on right side without using CSS and BOOTStrap –